# Uncaught Syntax error, unrecognized expression: 

Tags: jquery, wordpress

I've downloaded the script that is developed at http://www.alistapart.com/d/sprites2/examples/sprites2.js
It has worked on other sites, but I've never tried it with wordpress before.

The line that it fails on is the second one below:

```
function attachNavEvents(parent, myClass, setActive, hoverSpeed, style) {
$(parent + " ." + myClass).mouseover(function() {
    // create pseudo-link
    $(this).append('<div class="nav-' + myClass + '"></div>');
    // either slide or fade, depending on the style value
    if (style == "slide") {
        // slide down the pseudo-link ...
```

parent and myClass are both single word strings as far as I can tell. It doesn't make any difference if I comment out the whole mouseover function.
 In Chrome it comes up with the error

```
Uncaught Syntax error, unrecognized expression: .
```

When I go into the Javascript console and type in $(parent + " ." + myClass).mouseover(function(){}); it returns the jquery object no problems.

The jquery installation is working fine in other places. I have also tried it when replacing the jQuery variable with something like var $j =jquery.noConfict()

What is going on?!

Comment: Sounds like `myClass` is empty.

Comment: Have it `console.log` `parent + " ." + myClass` so you can see the result.

Comment: Thanks for the console.log tip. Easy to see what was giong on then. I had a li elsewhere in the markup with no class.